# How to separate iOS SDK from iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have created one project using third party SDK.
I have done some changes in SDK and improves it more.
I want to separate out SDK in such a way that any one can use my SDK in there project.
just as same I have taken it before from somewhere else and used in my project

Is there any standard way to separate out SDK from App?

Comment: your question is not clear as to what exactly you have performed and what is your requirement?

Comment: I have used one third party SDK in my app, modified it, now I want to separate out same SDK and send to another person in same way as I take it before from someone else

Comment: When you say u have used a third party SDK, have you manually added the SDK and its classes and then changed the classes or have you used some manager like Cocoapods or Carthage?

Comment: I have manually added SDK and modified it

Comment: What have you modified? the classes in it?

Comment: Yes, also please check my updated question

Comment: Download the same SDK, chalk out the classes you have have changed, and replace those classes from the downloaded SDK you have. If its working in your project, adding the newly formed one by someone else should work too.
But the trick is you have to do it manually

Comment: Separate it into a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you took it on a github, if not - let's anyway take github as an example.

First, when you did improves some code of third party library / sdk - i hope you still holding all the code in the same classes or at least connected classes, other way it will hard to work for that code. So, you should just take the code you improved and to [contribute](https://guides.github.com/activities/contributing-to-open-source/). Go over link it will describe you the process of how to support projects with your code.